# Why I can not change disable prop of element

Tags: jquery

Please tell me why I can not change disable property of select with this selections

As you see I get this html while success of ajax but I put the link call to the on click function

```js
$( ".kredits_area" ).on( "click", ".bestehende_edit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var block=$( this ).closest('.bestehende_data');
    console.log(block);
    console.log(block.find('.select_bestehende'))
    var darlehencenehmer =  block.find('.select_bestehende');

    console.log(darlehencenehmer);
   darlehencenehmer.prop('disabled', false);

$.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      url: "/" + "<?echo $admin_type?>" + "/get_kredit_history",
      data: {
        id: << ? echo $credit - > id ? >
      },
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      success: function(data) {
          $('.bestehende').css('display', 'none');
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                console.log(value.Darlehencenehmer)
                $('.kredits_area').append(
                    '<div class="bestehende_data" id="bestehende_data_' + value.id + '" style="margin-left:10px;">' +
                    '<div class="bestehende_header"><h3 style="display:inline-block" >Kredit ' + (key + 1) + '</h3>' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-default bestehende_edit" style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;color:blue;display:inline-block" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>' +
                    '<a class="btn btn-default bestehende_delete" style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;color:red;display:inline-block" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> </a>' +
                    '</div>' +
```

Comment: Please post some relevant HTML for this, it is hard to say without it, but from just looking at the code, if you set a break-point what does the variable `block` get set to?

Comment: Wrap your code inside $(document).ready() function.

Comment: Did you check the value of `block`?   If it has more than one class, it will be with spaces, eg "class1 bold" so your selector will be `$(".class1 bold > .darl")` which won't be what you're expecting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: Can you also provide more information as to the actual problem?  Eg does the click handler get called at all (if not, then see @SudhirOjha comment, if it does, then you've wasted SuhirOjha's time as that won't be the cause).

Comment: `console.log(jqueryObject)` probably won't give you anything useful, try `console.log(darlehencenehmer.length)`

Comment: @freedomn-m - Or better yet, instead of stumbling around in the dark with a `console.log` torch, he could *turn on the lights* using the debugger built into his browser. :-)

Comment: I put html code

Comment: console.log(darlehencenehmer.length) == 0

Comment: So the issue is with your selector - which means the issue is with setting the value of `block`.

Comment: value of block has only one class == bestehende_data

Comment: Yes, from the html/code provided.  So your selector is `$('.bestehende_data > .darlehencenehmer')` (find elements with class darlehencenehmer that are children of bestehende_data)  - but there's no `<div class='darlehencenehmer'` anywhere,  let alone as a child of `bestehende_data`

Comment: There are no decendants of your top most div with class `.bestehende_data` that have class `.darlehencenehmer`

Comment: Look at the code please I can not get child element as a class from object

Comment: You can't get child element if it doesn't exist.  It's like saying: Here's "ABC", ok, so give me "X".  X just isn't there.